# How do I reference a token?

Tags: sitecore-client, jwt-token

I created a token. When I write it on CMS field to call it, it doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please add more details of the specific example. Also, does this answer your question? https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/sitecore-experience-manager/standard-values-for-data-template-fields.html